# How to show bar only with barcode of Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, barcode

I want to show a barcode code39 without the code at the bottom.

I'm using the component barcode of PrimeFaces 6.0. This is the code I'm using:

```
<p:barcode id="codigoBarras" type="code39" value="#{bienControl.bienSelected.idBien}" format="svg" alt="Codigo de Barras" height="30" width="300" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Primefaces generate image for this component and has not attribute for hide the code, so you can only put a <div> over this component for hide the code.

Answer (score 0):

I debug this issue. It might be bug of primefaces6.0
**Used Below code:**

```
<p:barcode value="code39" type="code39"/>
```

**Output:**
[image]

The above image looking for **http://localhost:8080/LoginExample/faces/javax.faces.resource/dynamicconten…d=TpWw%2Bzz7eLk%3D&pfdrt=barcode&gen=code39&fmt=code39&pfdrid_c=true&ori=0**  
this src, so its not avalible.

Then i changed src by inspecting the browser then it worked.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This 'code39.gif' is not something PF generates. Are you sure you did not put that image somewhere yourself? The generated urls are used in the PF showcase as well (running 6.0.6)

Comment: code39.gif is image name. Primefaces should generate the src="code39.gif" instead of its generating different url. (Like this: http://localhost:8080/LoginExample/faces/javax.faces.resource/dynamicconten…d=TpWw%2Bzz7eLk%3D&pfdrt=barcode&gen=code39&fmt=code39&pfdrid_c=true&ori=0 ). Might be problem with internal classes.

Comment: What does this answer has to do with the question?